# PHP : Array Insertions and Display

Tags: php, arrays

I have a SQL query which I'm executing through php. The query results are being displayed correctly.

What am I doing wrong here?? Instead of displaying the results I want to store them in an array and display them later in the below `while` loop.

```
$arr = array();    
$sql = "SELECT itemName,itemRating from $userName WHERE itemName IN ( SELECT itemName from $user )";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$i=0;

if($result)
{
                while($row1=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                {
                        //echo $row1[0]." ".$row1[1]."<br>";
                        arr[$i]=$row1[0]; //Line 40
                        $i++;   
                }
}

$j=0;

while($j < $i)
{
    echo $arr[$j];
    $j++;
}
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Project/calculateSimilarity.php on line 40

Comment: You missing `$` prefix for $arr variable.

Comment: It will be $arr[$i]=$row1[0];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope it help..

```
$arr=array();    
    $sql="SELECT itemName,itemRating from $userName WHERE itemName IN ( SELECT itemName from $user )";
        $result=$conn->query($sql);
        $i=0;
        if($result)
        {
                while($row1=mysqli_fetch_row($result))
                {
                        array_push($arr,$row1[$i]); //Line 40
                        $i++;   
                }
        }
        $j=0;
        while($j<$i)
        {
            echo $arr[$j];
            $j++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $arr[$i]=$row1[0];
```

use it like this..

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten the $ dollar sign in front

change:

```
arr[$i]=$row1[0]; //Line 40
```

to:

```
$arr[$i]=$row1[0]; //Line 40
```